# Trouble with kafka example

Tags: apache-kafka

I downloaded Apache Kafka and successfully completed the quickstart . When i tried running the example program provided, I got an error :

> cannot load main class.

I dont know what I'm missing I even set the classpath.

Comment: Can you explain the Problem clearly by posting the error and code which you have made

Answer (score -1):

Run this command if you are on Amazon EC2:
sudo yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel

javac must be there. For that you need both JDK and JRE. You probably only have JRE installed.